# Conformal mapping problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Map the region of the plane outside the circles $|z - 1| = 1$ and $|z + 1| = 1$ conformally onto the exterior of the unit disk so that the points at infinity correspond to one another and the mapping is symmetric in the coordinate axes.

Comment: What similar conformal maps have you seen before?  What difficulty do you have adapting them to solve this problem?